# How to grant DevOps pipeline access to app service API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

In my pipeline file, after I deploy to an app service slot (which has network restrictions enabled), I want to execute an API on the app service, but keep getting `403 - Forbidden`.

Here is my powershell task:

```
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment:
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            condition: eq(variables.deployToSlot, 'true')
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                $repoUrl = "https://$(azureWebAppName)-staging.azurewebsites.net/api/warmup"
                Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $repoUrl -Method "GET" -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

I added `AzureDevOps` service tag as inbound rule under network settings on the app service slot, thinking this would allow the API call from the pipeline to succeed:

[image]

Here is the result:

```
Error 403 - Forbidden
The web app you have attempted to reach has blocked your access.
```

Comment: try adding the inbound rule for the `scm.azurewebsites.net`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To grant access with MS-hosted agent, add "AzureCloud.region" service tag as inbound rule under network settings on your app service slot. Make sure to add all of your region's service tags. Check this link for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#networking

[image]

[image]

Also, from your API script, I could not see any credential. For example, username password or PAT.

Comment: Our DevOps org is located in "westeurope". However, when adding service tag "AzureCloud.westeurope" to the inbound rules it still does not work. How to change it?